# How to stabilize cyclic tridiagonal matrix algorithm?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, problem-solving

I've received a task which is:

Solve equation by cyclic tridiagonal matrix algorithm:
$$ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}} = \lambda*\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}, 
\\ x\in[0,1]\ t\in[0,1] 
\\ f(t=0,x) = \phi(t)
\\ f(t,x = 0) = f(t,x=1)$$

So, I've chosen the **inverted triangle scheme** and approximated derivatives like this:

$$\frac{f((m+1)*\tau, n*h) - f(m*\tau, n*h)}{\tau} = \lambda\frac{f((m+1)*\tau, (n+1)*h) - f((m+1)*\tau, (n-1)*h)}{2h},\ where$$
$\tau=\frac{t_{max} - t_{min}}{M}$, $h=\frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{N} $, and $m\in[0, M-1]$, $n\in[1, N-1]$

So far so good, that is what I found about cyclic tridiagonal matrix algorithm:

*Cyclic tridiagonal matrix algorithm is applayble for such systems:*
$$a_1f_N-c_1f_1+b_1f_2 = -\phi_1
\\a_if_{i-1}-c_if_i+b_if_{i+1}=-\phi_2
\\...
\\a_Nf_{N-1}-c_Nf_N+b_NF_1=-\phi_N
\\a_{i+N}=a_{i},b_{i+N}=b_{i},c_{i+N}=c_{i},f_{i+N}=f_{i}$$

Okay, let's reformulate my task:
$$\frac{-\tau\lambda}{2h}f((m-1)*\tau, n*h)-f(m*\tau, n*h) + \frac{\tau\lambda}{2h}f((m+1)*\tau, n*h) = -f(m*\tau, n*h) $$

Hooray, I have $a=\frac{-\tau\lambda}{2h},\ c=1,\ b=\frac{\tau\lambda}{2h}\ and\ \phi=f(m*\tau, n*h)$

And the next line in the book is:

*Cyclic tridiagonal algorithm is only stable for $a_i>0,\ b_i>0, c_i>a_i+b_i$*

Poof, my solution is wrong, because **there is no way, $a_i$ and $b_i$ could be both positive or negative**, because they are coefficients in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and they **always have different signs.**

Nevertheless, I've implemented algorithm, and of course it did not converge. I've tried two different versions, one is [cyclic tridiagonal matrix algorithm(pdf)](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~stsynkov/book_sample_material/Sections_5.4-5.5.pdf), but I've got same results.

So my question is: am I wrong? Or is my teacher wrong? Or is there a way to stabilize this algorithm for my task?

It is not one question, but I'm confused)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was my bad. To be stable $$|c| > |a|+|b|$$ condition should be accomplished, which is entirely possible.